# Better understand of discounted cash flow

Tags: discounting

I try to understand about DCF.
reading this article
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dcf.asp
in 
Alternative Investments part,
can't figure out what's the calculation is used to get to $289,157.47 current value

copying from the site above:

> Alternative Investments An investor could set their DCF discount rate
>   equal to the return they expect from an alternative investment of
>   similar risk. For example, Aaliyah could invest $500,000 in a new home
>   that she expects to be able to sell in 10 years for $750,000.
>   Alternatively, she could invest her $500,000 in a real estate
>   investment trust (REIT) that is expected to return 10% per year for
>   the next 10 years.
>
> To simplify the example, we will assume Aaliyah is not accounting for
>   the substitution costs of rent or tax effects between the two
>   investments. All she needs for her DCF analysis is the discount rate
>   (10%) and the future cash flow ($750,000) from the future sale of her
>   home. This DCF analysis only has one cash flow so the calculation will
>   be easy.
>
> In this example, Aaliyah should not invest in the house because her
>   DCF analysis shows that its future cash flows are only worth
>   $289,157.47 today. Once tax effects, rent, and other factors are
>   included, Aaliyah may find that the DCF is a little closer to the
>   current value of the home. Although this example is oversimplified it
>   should help illustrate some of the issues of DCF including finding
>   appropriate discount rates and making reliable future predictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The video embedded in the article gives the general formula at 1:16 in, albeit amongst annoying background music and quick animations.  For this particular question there is only one cash flow (the sale of the house), and they are discounting the $750,000 received in ten years back to today's value, using a rate of return of 10% due to the (supposedly) equivalent risk of a REIT:

```
 750,000 * (1 + 0.10)^-10 = 289,157.47
```

In other words, if you invested 289K today at a 10% annual rate of return, in ten years you'd have 750K.

```
 289,157.47 * (1 + 0.10) ^ 10 = 750,000
```

To be honest, there are much better articles throughout the internet that explain discounting without the theatrics or incomplete examples.

Comment: Thank you @D Stanley, could you advice good resource? this one is among first on finance searches in Google

Comment: @KochavaKlimuk Specific resources are off-topic, but I would just try some of the other search results. If self-learning doesn't help, find a basic finance course at your local college or university.